# How to delete the second word using : as separator on java script

Tags: javascript

so i have string like this

```
accept : menerima 
accuse : menuduh 
achieve : mencapai 
acquire : memperoleh 
adapt : menyesuaikan 
add : menambahkan
```

and how to delete the second word using : as separator,
And make the result like this.

```
accept 
accuse 
achieve 
acquire
adapt 
add
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach to a regex would be to loop over the lines, and split the `:` using a map.

```js
const string = `accept : menerima
accuse : menuduh 
achieve : mencapai 
acquire : memperoleh 
adapt : menyesuaikan 
add : menambahkan`;

const lines = string.split("\n")
.map((line) => line.split(" : ")[0])

// Optionally if you would like to return the output as a single string
.join("\n"); 

console.log(lines);
```

Answer (score 3):

A regex will work.

```js
const rx = /\s+:.*$/mg
str.replace(rx, '')
```

https://regex101.com/r/sV2TnQ/1

The `g` flag will replace multiple occurances.  The `m` flag lets `$` match end of line or document.

So 'spaces', a 'colon', and 'all to end of line'

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
const str = 'accept : menerima'

console.log(str.slice(0,str.indexOf(":")))
```

You can create one method, which will take string as input and will return new string.

```
const txt = 'accept : menerima'

function getCroppedString(str){
    return str.slice(0,str.indexOf(":"));
}

getCroppedString(txt)

console.log(getCroppedString(txt));
```

```js
const str = 'accept : menerima'

console.log(str.slice(0,str.indexOf(":")))
```